# trouver son compte à quelque chose

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs, y

Je me demande si la phrase suivante est exacte : " C'est une relation où je ne trouve pas mon compte " pour dire : qui ne me satisfait pas.
Le plus souvent, on entend : " j'y trouve mon compte, je n'y trouve pas mon compte" mais dans ma phrase (incorrecte ?) il y a déjà un pronom relatif qui rendrait l'emploi de "y" superflu..

Answer (score 5):

« C'est une relation où je ne trouve pas mon compte » est tout à fait correct, il ne faut pas y mettre *y*.

Quand on dit « je n'y trouve pas mon compte » le pronom personnel *y* renvoie à une situation qui est nommée ailleurs dans le contexte.

Deux exemples :

> - [Même si l’éleveur met un mois de plus pour finir ses taurillons, il semble y trouver son compte](http://www.agriculteur-normand.com/actualites/ration-endives-bovins-et-eleveurs-y-trouvent-leur-compte:5DDK9W2P.html).

*Y* renvoie à l'arrangement entre agriculteurs et éleveurs que le journaliste vient d'expliquer. Le journaliste aurait pu formuler la phrase autrement :

- l'éleveur semble trouver son compte dans cet arrangement.
- C'est un arrangement dans lequel l'éleveur trouve son compte.

> - [Un sous-sol familial polyvalent : pour que tous y trouvent leur compte](https://www.lecourrierdusud.ca/un-sous-sol-familial-polyvalent-pour-que-tous-y-trouvent-leur-compte/)

*Y* représente le concept de « sous-sol polyvalent » qui est développé dans l'article. Le journaliste aurait pu formuler le titre autrement :

- toute la famille trouve son compte dans l'aménagement d'un sous-sol polyvalent.

On peut dire :

- Je ne trouve pas mon compte dans cette relation.
- Cette relation, je n'y trouve pas mon compte.
- C'est une relation où je ne trouve pas mon compte.
- C'est une relation dans laquelle je ne trouve pas mon compte.

Answer (score -2):

Dans la [4e](https://academie.atilf.fr/4/consulter/COMPTE?options=motExact) édition du ditionnaire de l'Académie (1762) on trouve la définition suivante.

> On dit figurément, Faire son compte, trouver son compte, pour dire, Trouver du profit & de l'avantage.
>
> - Il a bien fait son compte dans cette recette.
> - Il a bien fait son petit compte dans ce traité.
> - Il y a trouvé son compte.
> - Ne choquez pas cet homme-là, vous n'y trouverez pas votre compte.

Dans la [8e](https://academie.atilf.fr/8/consulter/COMPTE?options=motExact) (1835)
 l'expression semble avoir perdu de sa force

> Fig. et fam., Trouver son compte, Trouver du profit, de l'avantage.
>
> - Il m'a rendu service et il a trouvé son compte.
> - N'offensez pas cet homme-là, vous n'y trouveriez pas votre compte.

Dans la [9e](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/COMPTE?options=motExact) édition la rubrique a disparu et fait place seulement à la forme courante dans laquelle figure le pronom « y ».

> On y trouve son compte : on y trouve avantage, intérêt, profit.

Les références suivantes ne donnent que la définition de « y trouver son compte » ou seulement des exemples où ne figure que cet emploi avec le pronom « y », sauf exception.

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/trouver_son_compte
https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/definition/y_trouver_son_compte.php
https://fr.glosbe.com/fr/fr/trouver%20son%20compte Sur 25 exemples seulement 5 comportent le pronom « y ».
https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/trouver+son+compte.html Sur 30 exemples on en trouve 6 ne comprenant pas « y ».

- En d’autres termes, elle mettrait l’accent sur les aspirations pour l’avenir et non sur les cicatrices du passé, sur l’intégration et non sur les clivages, sur une situation où chacun trouve son compte et non sur un jeu à somme nulle.
- Pour le Président du FIDA, les rapports entre son institution et le Mécanisme mondial sont fondés sur un rapport où chacun trouve son compte.
- Interrogé à propos du pari, le Capitaine de frégate Joe Sipos, commandant du NCSM Regina, a déclaré : « C’est un pari où tout le monde trouve son compte; personne n’y perd.
- Il a probablement trouvé son compte au milieu de toutes ces infirmières.
- Mandat L'Office est parmi les nombreux partenaires qui contribuent à la mise en place d'un réseau de transport où chacun trouve son compte.

En conclusion on peut dire que l'expression se fait rare mais qu'elle est encore utilisée, donc correcte. On remarque dans les exemples que « y » ne figure pas dans l'expression lorsque l'on trouve « où » et ne peut y figurer puisque « où » le remplace.

Il est conseillé dans la référence suivante de ne pas utiliser cette expression pour parler des relations humaines.

https://www.francaisfacile.com/forum/lire.php?num=7&msg=105095&titre=Trouver+son+compte

« On peut éventuellement dire "je ne trouve pas mon compte dans ma relation avec X" mais il vaut mieux dire "je ne suis pas tout à fait satisfait de ma relation avec X" ou quelque chose d'approchant. »